# Calculating difference in values in a dataframe by grouping by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I have  a dataframe in the form off:

```
  station   num_bikes   Rush hour? num_racks hour
  Botanic   3           yes-am     9         9
  Botanic   2           no         10        14
  Botanic   10          no         2         20
  Queens    6           no         10        5
  Queens    10          yes-pm     6         18
  Queens    12          yes-pm     4         19
  Queens    1           no         15        7
```

The num_bikes is the number of bikes available at that station, num_racks is the number of racks available.I am attempting to calculate the total number of arrivals and departures of bikes at each station to determine the total number of transactions. The code I am using produces the error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1
```

The code was:

```
df_filtered['diff'] = df_filtered.groupby(['Rush hour?', 'station'])      [['num_bikes']].diff()
```

Expected output:

```
  station     Rush hour?  arrivals  departures
  Botanic     yes-am      0         0
  Botanic     no          8         0
  Queens      no          0         5
  Queens      yes-pm      0         2
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try using single bracket around `num_bikes`, i.e., `groupby(...)['num_bikes'].diff()`

Comment: can you provided an expected output

Comment: when i use a single bracket i get ValueError: No axis named station for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Your expected output is identical to your expected input? Then problem solved, QED.

Comment: Not sure if you're having an error because of this, but `Station` != `station` at least in *nix environments.

Comment: the same error still appears

Comment: It seems to me like you would want to do the diff() before the groupby, since you'll have different indexing and also order is important for diff

Comment: Then once you have the negative and positives from diff() you can add two new columns called `arrivals` and `departures` that are set based on a mask of whether the diff() result was negative or positive, fill blank values with 0s in those columns, and then do a groupby and add arrivals/departures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have tried, let me know if it doesn't seem right:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_filtered = pd.DataFrame([
    ('Botanic' ,  3      ,     'yes-am' ,    9    ,     9),
  ('Botanic'  , 2       ,    'no'        , 10     ,   14),
  ('Botanic'  , 10     ,     'no'        , 2      ,   20),
  ('Queens'   , 6     ,      'no'       ,  10     ,   5),
  ('Queens'   , 10   ,       'yes-pm'   ,  6      ,   18),
  ('Queens'   , 12  ,        'yes-pm'   ,  4      ,   19),
  ('Queens'   , 1  ,         'no'       ,  15     ,   7)
])

df_filtered.columns = ['station',   'num_bikes',   'Rush hour?', 'num_racks', 'hour']

df_filtered['diff'] = df_filtered['num_bikes'].diff().fillna(0)
df_filtered['arrivals'] = df_filtered['diff'][df_filtered['diff'] > 0]
df_filtered['departures'] = df_filtered['diff'][df_filtered['diff'] < 0]
df_filtered.drop(columns='diff', inplace=True)
df_filtered[['departures','arrivals']] = df_filtered[['departures','arrivals']].astype(float).fillna(0)
df_filtered.groupby(['Rush hour?', 'station'])[['arrivals','departures','num_bikes']].sum()
```

[image: Dataframe Screenshot]

These groupby results may not retain the original order of the input data frame so it may seem confusing but these are the net results of arrivals/departures as a snapshot of the row group.

Comment: When i tried this i get the error :unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Did you use `astype(float)` ? If you print`df_filtered.dtypes` are your numeric columns listed as floats/ints or object/str ?

Comment: yes, now the error states cannot reindex from a duplicate index?

Comment: @caston1414 Are you using a Jupyter notebook? If so, you will need to restart the kernel and re-run all code or ensure that all code can be run multiple times without side effects.

Comment: yes i am using Jupiter notebook, i will try that thank you